# Recover Picasa 3.0 temp

Tags: picasa

I used Google picasa 3.0   to scan from my scanner but forgot to complete the import process. I saw that it had created a PicasaTemp folder before I hit the cancel button. How can I recover the scans ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your file manager or windows explorer search for the folder **PicasaTemp**.

It could be in some locations:
- picasa instalation direcory
- windows temp folder (default is c:\windows\temp)
- user temp folder (default is c:\Document and Settings\MyUserName\Temp or c:\Users\MyUserName\Temp)
- AppData folder (in your user folder c:\Document and Settings\MyUserName\AppData)

Comment: i saw that the PicasaTemp was created, but it was removed immediately after i hit the cancel button by mistake instead of the "import all" button

Comment: sorry for the late answer, the only thing that you can do is to use a undelete software like O&O UnErase or a free program NTFS Undelete
(http://ntfsundelete.com/) and try to recover those files